# Parse html to text and text to html in DRF

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, markdown

I'm having forum, the forum thread and reply content are stored in the DB as markdown text. While Saving i need to convert `HTML to Markdown text by html2text` and While retrieving Convert the `Markdown text to HTML by Mistune`. For that parsing i'm using two package. Is this better way orelse suggest some better solution

Comment: Welcome to SO. First of all your post seems unclear. Secondly, this site is not a code-writing service and is not meant for delivering complete solutions. Users are expected to show some effort and code whilst SO is here to help you solve specific programming problems along the way. Have you tried anything already? Please read: https://stackoverflow.com/help/asking

Comment: i'm already using the package for my requirement. But i'm asking whether it's better or not. if not suggest me something @MaciejJureczko

Comment: What is better than what exactly? Please clarify (edit) your original post.

Comment: updated @MaciejJureczko

Comment: If you take the two-step approach you run into problems.. if not then SO is not the site to ask. Try other more suited exchange sites from SO or forums related to your topic? If you do run into problems then you can edit your question and show the problem. Then it suites SO rules.

Comment: The post seems more clear now. Ok so... if you are asking about "are there better libraries/modules/packages" then the question is off-topic here (please see: https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic). For this to be a good SO question, you would have to publish your own solution to for the conversions, and even then it might be more of a question for codereview.stackexchange.com. If it works for you as it is, then it is a good solution in terms of SO.